# Sidetree protocol

Tags: protocols, bitcoin, decentralized-identity, decentralized-identifiers

I started studying the sidetree protocol but I can't understand how it works and the architecture. The documentation says (https://identity.foundation/sidetree/spec/#network-topology) that sidetree is a Level 2 protocol that can fit on blockchain as Bitcoin, Ethereum...,but I don't understand how it works and that is the role of some components (for example CAS). Could someone give me an example?

Answer (score 0):

This [sidetree repo](https://github.com/decentralized-identity/sidetree) contains a reference implementation of the sidetree specification, which uses IPFS as its underlying CAS. CAS/IPFS is simply the storage for all the data generated on this layer 2 network.

[ION](https://github.com/decentralized-identity/ion) is a sidetree based network that runs on top of Bitcoin.

[Element](https://github.com/decentralized-identity/element) is a sidetree based network that runs on top of Ethereum.